# Div vanishes when i use "align-items : center"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a box which has on left and right side a blue "div" and in the middle a larger purple "div". My Problem is that when i write "align-items : center" all "div" vanishes but i dont know why. Can you help me?

This is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox Playground</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

    <section id="anotherExample">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="mainContent"></div>
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS Code

```
#anotherExample{
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #003049;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: center;*/
 }
 
 section .sidebar{
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow:1 ;
    flex-basis: 200px;

 }

 section .mainContent{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    flex-grow:2 ;
    flex-basis: 200px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**All `div` vanish because they have no `height` when `align-items: center`.**

For flex items, the default `align-items` behave as `stretch`. The three `div` are stretched to their container height.

When you set `align-items: center`, the three `div` are centered on the cross-axis, but they are not visible due to no height (since they do not have content or a set height).

If you give them a height such as `height: 100%`, you can see the three `div` again.

[More about `align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Example:

```css
#anotherExample {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #003049;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*   With this turn on the div will no height will vanish */
  align-items: center;
}

section .sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  /*   Give div a height to see it when align-items is center */
  height: 100%;
}

section .mainContent {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  /*   Give div a height to see it when align-items is center */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

<section id="anotherExample">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="mainContent"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you apply `align-items: center`, the `height` of `div` elements are set to `0`. You can try to add the `height` property to divs to see them again as `#anotherExample` is parent of those `div` elements.

```css
#anotherExample{
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #003049;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
 
 section .sidebar{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-basis: 200px;

 }

 section .mainContent{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    flex-grow:2 ;
    flex-basis: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

    <section id="anotherExample">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="mainContent"></div>
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
    </section>
```